# How to change the value of a variable using a UISwitch?

Tags: swift, swift4, uiswitch

I am brand new to swift and trying to get my bearings. I am currently working on a switch to toggle the volume on/off for these oscillator objects I have made using AudioKit. I have no problems with the AudioKit part but I just can't seem to figure out how to change the 'volume' variables from absolute 0 to their 'on' levels using a UISwitch.

Please help!

I have tried a number of things but after much searching I have gotten to this point. I have decided to declare the variables for each volume control to be their 'on' values, and then added the UISwitch and used an if statement to toggle the volumes.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var Fsys = 5.00

    //VOLUMES HERE:
    var volumeMono = 0.2
    var volumeBinaural = 0.6

    var A1 = 54.00
    var A2 = 108.00

    @IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            volumeMono = (volumeMono) * (1)
            volumeBinaural = (volumeBinaural) * (1)
        }
        else {
            volumeMono = (volumeMono) * (0)
            volumeBinaural = (volumeBinaural) * (0)
            }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let generator = AKOperationGenerator(channelCount: 2) { _ in


            let leftOutput = AKOperation.sineWave(frequency: A2, amplitude: volumeBinaural)
            let rightOutput = AKOperation.sineWave(frequency: A2 + Fsys, amplitude: volumeMono)

            return [leftOutput, rightOutput]
        }

        AudioKit.output = generator
        AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
        try! AudioKit.start()
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
        }

        generator.start()
    }


}
```

It was my hope that this would multiply the variables by 0 when the switch was off (stopping the sound of the oscillators) and when it was on, the switch function would multiply the variables by 1, making the audio output match the declared variables.

When I run the build, the system defaults to the volumes declared at the beginning and the switch does not do anything.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called exactly once when the ViewController loads. At this point, you are creating a generator using trailing closure syntax. The closure will capture the values of volumeMono and volumeBinaural at that time. They will be 0.2 and 0.6 respectively. Since the closure has captured those values, the leftOutput and rightOutput of the generator will never change.

If your switch were to work, the logic is flawed. Once you multiply the values by 0, they'll always be 0. I don't know enough about AudioKit to recommend creating a new generator when the switch is toggled or whether you can tweak some values, but that's the reason your switch isn't having any affect.

Comment: Ahhh okay, that makes sense! I moved the generator into a separate function that is called when the switch is activated. Thank you!